# Java Database Display all Country Info from Country Database Table

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting, methods

I am working on a Java assignment that requires to change the Country class so it prints every Country from a Country Database Table, not just one Country. I've tried various instances but cannot get it to display all them. I'm very new to Java so I know that I'm messing up the syntax somehow, or it's blatantly in front of my face and I've just been working on this for too long and need another set of eyes. Here is what I have so far to display one Country from the Country Table.

```
    public class CountryMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadCountryDB rcdb = new ReadCountryDB();
        List<Country> countries = rcdb.getCountries();

        Country firstCountry = countries.get(0);
        System.out.println("First country:");
        System.out.println("Name: " + firstCountry.getName()
                           + "  Population: " + firstCountry.getPopulation()
                           + "  Median Age: " + firstCountry.getMedianAge());
      }
}
```

I know it the "Country firstCountry = countries.get(0)" method section that I need to change, which I've tried getAll which is undefined, but I'm confused on what I need to define so it pulls everything from the Country Database.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using a `for loop` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the right count in the `countries` list, then you can loop through the list to work with every element as -

```
for (Country country : countries) {
  System.out.println("Name: " + country.getName()
                       + "  Population: " + country.getPopulation()
                       + "  Median Age: " + country.getMedianAge());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already pulled all countries by the `rcdb.getCountries()`, then just use a loop to print out all countries:

```
for (Country country : countries) {   
     System.out.println("Country:");
     System.out.println("Name: " + country.getName()
                       + "  Population: " + country.getPopulation()
                       + "  Median Age: " + country.getMedianAge());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

loop it

```
   public class CountryMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReadCountryDB rcdb = new ReadCountryDB();
    List<Country> countries = rcdb.getCountries();
    for(int i=0; i<coutries.size; i++){
     Country firstCountry = countries.get(i);
     System.out.println("First country:");
     System.out.println("Name: " + firstCountry.getName()
                       + "  Population: " + firstCountry.getPopulation()
                       + "  Median Age: " + firstCountry.getMedianAge());
    }
  }
}
```